# Can not access Facebook session - UnknownError: Invalid application

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

I'm using Prime31 SocialNetworking plugin for Unity3D with Facebook SDK 3.5 and trying to login Facebook on the Android 2.3.5 device. Facebook application is installed on my device and a Facebook user is logged in prior to application launch. Default login behaviour `SSO_WITH_FALLBACK` is used.

When I initiate a login from my application I observe the following behaviour:

1. When the application starts the Facebook session is in `CREATED` state.
2. A permissions dialog prompts me to allow basic read access for my application.
3. I click OK and then my main application activity is shown instead of Facebook's login dialog (maybe it's intentional but `Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()` and `Session.setActiveSession(null)` are called prior to `new Session.OpenRequest(FacebookPlugin.getActivity())` inside Prime31 plugin).
4. My application's Facebook session is not opened (is in `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` state).

The logcat reports me these lines (package name and Facebook app ID are replaced):

```
I/Prime31 ( 5077): FacebookPlugin: openActiveSession.call with state: CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, exception: com.facebook.FacebookException: Log in attempt aborted.
I/Prime31 ( 5077): session state: OPENING
I/ActivityManager( 1444): Starting activity: Intent { act=SSO_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.facebook.LoginActivity (has extras) } from pid 5077
I/Prime31 ( 5077): FacebookPlugin: openActiveSession.call with state: OPENING, exception: null
V/ActivityManager( 1444): Checking to restart com.facebook.LoginActivity: changed=0x0, handles=0x0
V/ActivityManager( 1444): oldConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=250/2 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=3 skin=default fontsize=3}
V/ActivityManager( 1444): newConfig={ scale=1.0 imsi=250/2 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=3 skin=default fontsize=3}
V/WindowManager( 1444): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40e61148 token=HistoryRecord{408389c8 MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}} @ 6621760
I/ActivityManager( 1444): Displayed MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +547ms
V/WindowManager( 1444): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{40c836a8 token=HistoryRecord{40d3d640 MY_PACKAGE_NAME/com.facebook.LoginActivity}} @ 6621760
D/NativeCrypto( 3576): returned from sslSelect() with result 1, error code 2
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576): Exception during service
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Invalid application MY_VALID_APP_ID
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:81)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:110)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:291)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:272)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:29)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:152)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:366)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:259)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:293)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at com.facebook.common.executors.HandlerExecutorServiceImpl$ListenableScheduledFuture.run(HandlerExecutorServiceImpl.java:268)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 3576):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
W/Bundle  ( 5077): Key com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_VERSION expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle  ( 5077): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
W/Bundle  ( 5077): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1040)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:3685)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaLoginDialogAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:821)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:272)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:238)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.getTokenCompleted(AuthorizationClient.java:772)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler$1.completed(AuthorizationClient.java:731)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.callback(PlatformServiceClient.java:144)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:128)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient$1.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:54)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
W/Bundle  ( 5077):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I logout from Facebook within the native app the behaviour slightly changes - the login screen appears, but when the main application activity is shown I get the same `CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` session state.

I've checked my application ID and hash key in the Facebook app settings: both are matching to my app's settings. Hash key logcatted by Prime31 plugin is the same as was created on my Windows evironment. When I changed app ID to something different I got another error - "invalid app id". So app id seems to be set up correctly. What else I might miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all who encounter similar issues check your **Facebook application sandbox mode** and currently active Facebook user when starting your application. In my case I was starting the application which was in the sandbox mode and the current **Facebook user was not from the granted list of users in the Facebook application settings**.

Answer (score 0):

In case that helps anyone, I had the same problem and it was due to the fact that my test phone had its time set 3-4 months in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the facebook application identifies itself with an ID not previously registered at facebook. Go to https://developers.facebook.com , register a new application and you will receive a numerical ID (something like 10 digits) which you should plant in the code. in **react-native-fbsdk**, this is called **facebook_app_id** or **facebook_application_id**.