# Facebook SDK works in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

If I'm using the debug key-store my Facebook integration works fine. But if I'm using my created key and created key store, Facebook is not working.

I also tried to extract the hash-key of my created key store and put it in the Facebook app settings, but still no luck.

What might the problem be, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind providing the logcat for the initializing process?

If initializing is ok, and the problem is that you are unable to connect to facebook.
Please check if you are in facebook sandbox mode setting and your facebook account is granted access/permission.

EDIT:

You may want to check out this thread too -
[Can not access Facebook session - UnknownError: Invalid application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612491/can-not-access-facebook-session-unknownerror-invalid-application)